# Can HTTP headers be used to tell if page has been through a proxy?

Tags: proxy, http, http-headers

Is there a way for an HTTP server to tell from HTTP headers if a proxy server has been involved in the connection?

Answer (score 4):

Not with certainty. Nice ones may add some headers. Less forthcoming ones might not. Your milage may vary depending on why/how you use the information.

Answer (score 1):

If the headers are enabled. Just for example I've got a Squid installation on pfSense (basically Squid on my router with a GUI). There I have 2 relevant options:

"Disable X-Forward
If not set, Squid will include your system's IP address or name in the HTTP requests it forwards.

Disable VIA
If not set, Squid will include a Via header in requests and replies as required by RFC2616."

Answer (score -1):

There are headers like X-Real-IP X-Forwared-For wich can help you to detect proxies.